# Multiple web.config on shared hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have two different applications deployed on common shared hosting (using [hostgator](http://www.hostgator.com/) services).

One application is deployed on root folder and another one is deployed in sub-folder created on root. But the application deployed in sub-folder is not using web.config file available in sub-folder, it is using same web.config available on root folder.

Please help me to find out way how to use different web.config files for all different sub-folders on shared hosting.

Comment: You need the subdirectory to run as an application in its own right.  How you do that is down to the tool (online or remote desktop) available to you

Comment: @freefaller: I have shared hosting not VPS or dedicated server so unable to implement your solution. Can you please help me for shared hosting.

Comment: Sorry @himanshum, I have no shared hosting experience... I've only ever dealt with dedicated servers. If you're still stuck get in touch with their technical support, I'm sure they'll be able to help, as you can't be the first person to have ever want to do this

Answer (score 2):

The only way to have a subdirectory act as a separate application with its own web.config is to configure it to be a separate IIS application.

In a dedicated hosting environment, you'd do this within IIS. However, the fact that you're on a shared hosting platform doesn't automatically make it impossible. Most shared hosting provides a web interface that you use to configure your site, and often - but not always - that interface will give you the ability to set up subfolders as separate applications.

I can't tell you whether you have this option or where it is, since I don't know what control-panel software/product your hosting uses (and even if I did, I probably wouldn't be familiar with that specific product/version, but it's worth having a dig around in your control panel to see if you can find it somewhere. If not, try contacting support - they might be able to point you in the right direction, they might offer to do it for you in IIS, or worst-case scenario is that they'll tell you they don't offer that service (at least then you'll know, and can start looking elsewhere for a new host).

Unfortunately, there's no other way to do this - you can't for example add a setting to the root web.config to tell it to treat a subfolder as a separate application, because applications exist at the IIS level not the ASP.NET level.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the code in the subfolder should be using the web.config in the root folder, *plus* the web.config in the subfolder. Exactly which settings are not being used in the subfolder?

It is not necessary to have the subfolder be an application just in order to get the two config files to merge. It is necessary if you want the sub web.config file to be independent.